# What does the 'self' keyword mean in WebWorkers

Tags: javascript, web-worker, self

I don't understand the 7,8,9 line:

```
var worker = new Worker('doWork.js');

worker.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
  console.log('Worker said: ', e.data);   // Here it send's the data.
}, false);

worker.postMessage('Hello World'); // Send data to our worker.



 //7 self.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
   //8   self.postMessage(e.data);
   //9 }, false);
```

What is doing this block of code? 
1.what code line fires the message event in line 7?
2.what data is passed in the postMessage on line 8?
3.what does self do here?

Comment: "Self" probably refers to an object (the "this"), however, it's probably in the context of an anonymous function, so they might have used "self" instead of the .bind() method. Can you post the rest of the code please? There's plenty more, I'm sure.

Comment: It's a reference to a [global object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope/self) in web workers, since they have no browsing context and no `window` object.

Comment: @JoshBeam I myself thought the same thing, it turns out it's a whole other world. See http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/

Comment: I don't understand why so many downvotes. It's a good question.

Comment: @php_nub_qq, interesting, thanks for pointing that out! I retracted my close vote, I'm curious to see the answer to this question.

Comment: @taxicala Bad title and strange formatting for the question itself I guess

Comment: @wonderb0lt Yes that could be the cause, but the question itself I believe is a good question.

Comment: In the webworker example on MDN they don't use `self` but `postMessage` directly. Not sure if there's a practical difference. MDN Example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the keyword `self` is used to approach the Worker’s API, which means that no matter the scope (even if its a closure) you will get access to the Worker's API (I'm not sure if you can redeclare `self` to something else and loose the Worker's API reference, but I believe it is protected by JS so you don't be able to override it).

And the following lines:

```
self.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
    self.postMessage(e.data);
}, false);
```

Are simply adding an event listener for the `'message'` event, which will send the data from the event back to the reference of the webworker in the context where it was spawned (most commonly the current browsers thread, or a parent worker). And we can quote what the `false` boolean determines:

> `useCapture` Optional If true, useCapture indicates that the user wishes
>   to initiate capture. After initiating capture, all events of the
>   specified type will be dispatched to the registered listener before
>   being dispatched to any EventTarget beneath it in the DOM tree. Events
>   which are bubbling upward through the tree will not trigger a listener
>   designated to use capture. See DOM Level 3 Events and JavaScript Event
>   order for a detailed explanation. If not specified, useCapture
>   defaults to false.
>
> > Note: For event listeners attached to the event
> >     target; the event is in the target phase, rather than capturing and
> >     bubbling phases. Events in the target phase will trigger all listeners
> >     on an element regardless of the useCapture parameter.
> >
> > Note: useCapture
> >     became optional only in more recent versions of the major browsers;
> >     for example, it was not optional prior to Firefox 6. You should
> >     provide this parameter for broadest compatibility.
>
> `wantsUntrusted`  If true, the listener will receive synthetic events
>   dispatched by web content (the default is false for chrome and true
>   for regular web pages). This parameter is only available in Gecko and
>   is mainly useful for the code in add-ons and the browser itself. See
>   Interaction between privileged and non-privileged pages for an
>   example.

From: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

A more technical description of the keyword `self`:

> The self read-only property of the WorkerGlobalScope interface returns
>   a reference to the WorkerGlobalScope itself. Most of the time it is a
>   specific scope like DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope, 
>   SharedWorkerGlobalScope, or ServiceWorkerGlobalScope.

Quoted from: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope/self